# Powershell script to iterate through folder and restore SQL backups

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am working on a PowerShell script which will loop through a directory containing SQL Server database backup .bak files; move the files to a different location; restore each of those files to the local SQL instance using OSQL.exe; output the SQL output to a log file.

This works OK, but I am willing to improve it.

```cs
$sourceBackupDirectory = "C:\FTP"
$sqlDatabaseLocation = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\"
$backupsLocation = "C:\DatabaseRestore\"

Get-ChildItem $sourceBackupDirectory -Filter "*.bak" -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination $backupsLocation #move files
$backupsLocationFiles = Get-ChildItem $backupsLocation -Filter "*.bak" #load files into array

$todayUK = Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd
$logsFolder = "LogFiles\"
$logFile = $backupsLocation + $logsFolder + $todayUK + ".txt"

foreach ($file in $backupsLocationFiles)
{
    $filePath = $backupsLocation + $file
    $file = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
    #$filePath
    #$file

    RestoreDB $file $filePath
}

function global:RestoreDB ([string] $newDBName, [string] $backupFilePath)
{
    [string] $dbCommand = "RESTORE DATABASE [$newDBName] " +
    "FROM    DISK = N'$backupFilePath' " +
    "WITH    FILE = 1, " + 
    "MOVE N'$newDBName' " + 
    "TO N'$sqlDatabaseLocation" + "$newDBName.mdf', " + 
    "MOVE N'$newDBName" + "_log' " +
    "TO N'$sqlDatabaseLocation" + "$newDBName" + "_log.ldf', " + 
    "NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 5"
    Write-Host $dbCommand

    OSQL.EXE -E -Q $dbCommand >> $logFile #this ouputs the SQL output into a logfile. 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Functions

They *must* be declared before they are called. This script would fail if run from a clean session the first time. Just make sure you have functions declared before they are called. At the beginning of a script is a natural in PowerShell. I came from a VBS background so this was odd for me at first too.

## Improved string concatenation

**In your function**

The format operator would be of great use here. Especially since you are putting the same variable in several places. Like in Quills answer use of here-string helps with the new lines. Note that is it not required you can just use and open and closing quotes to wrap the whole thing up.

```
    $dbCommand = "RESTORE DATABASE [{0}]
FROM    DISK = N'{1}'
WITH    FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'{0}' 
TO N'{2}{0}.mdf', 
MOVE N'{0}_log'
TO N'{2}{0}_log.ldf',
NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 5" -f $newDBName, $backupFilePath, $sqlDatabaseLocation
```

One could argue that readability is reduced but I think this makes it clearer. It removed all the `+` used for concatenation. No more need for repeated variables in the string. Casting it as a [string] is also redundant but that is just being nitpicky.

**For log files**

PowerShell is forgiving when it comes to variable expansion in strings. Since you are just dealing with string variables you can just do something simple like this.

```
$logFile = "$backupsLocation$logsFolder$todayUK.txt"
```

You can also use the Combine static method from `[system.io.path]`. This has the feature of being more resilient to the presence and lack of backslashes. It is not simple string concatenation so it is a little more robust.

```
$logFile = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($backupsLocation, $logsFolder, "$todayUK.txt")
```

Both of these commands would produce the same output.

## Simplify gathering files.

`Move-Item` has a passthru switch so that it will pass the moved item down the pipeline. No need to requery to get the files again.

```
$backupsLocationFiles = Get-ChildItem $sourceBackupDirectory -Filter "*.bak" -Recurse | 
    Move-Item -Destination $backupsLocation -PassThru
```

## Loop Calling Function

The loop where you are calling the function has some room for improvement.

You are using $file and changing its meaning from a file object then turning it into a simple string. Not really a best practice. Does not matter since you don't even really need it.

File objects returned from `Get-ChildItem` have a `basename` property which is exactly what you are trying to get from `[io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)`. While not what it was designed for `Join-Path` will also build the path for you without relying on string concatenation.

```
foreach ($file in $backupsLocationFiles){
    $backupPath = Join-Path -Path $backupsLocation -ChildPath $file.Name
    RestoreDB -newDBName $file.BaseName -backupFilePath $filePath 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly style things, but:

- You should store all your constants at the top (including `$logsFolder`)
- `#this ouputs the SQL output into a logfile`: you misspelled `outputs`
- You should use the string concatenation syntax:

> ```
> "TO N'$($sqlDatabaseLocation)$($newDBName)_log.ldf',"
> ```

- You only use `$todayUK` once, so you should include it directly as a string instead of declaring it.
- Instead of concatenating each string component together, use a multi line string operator like `@"` or a trailing backtick `.

> ```
>     [string] $dbCommand = @"RESTORE DATABASE [$newDBName]
> FROM    DISK = N'$backupFilePath' 
> WITH    FILE = 1,
> MOVE N'$newDBName'
> TO N'$($sqlDatabaseLocation)$($newDBName).mdf', 
> MOVE N'$($newDBName)_log'
> TO N'$($sqlDatabaseLocation)$($newDBName)_log.ldf',
> NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 5"
> ```

- Now, you can just directly call that string instead of assigning it to `$dbCommand`:

> ```
>     Write-Host @"RESTORE DATABASE [$newDBName]
> FROM    DISK = N'$backupFilePath' 
> WITH    FILE = 1,
> MOVE N'$newDBName' #more stuff here
> ```

Comment: Use of a here string is fine but you are missing the terminator that has to appear by itself on its own line. `"@`